# Handling Dropbox authentication response

Tags: ios, dropbox-api

Dropbox documentation explains by default the response for authentication gets fired into Appdelegate.m
How do I make the same fire my own class's delegate?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url
    sourceApplication:(NSString *)source annotation:(id)annotation {
    if ([[DBSession sharedSession] handleOpenURL:url]) {
        if ([[DBSession sharedSession] isLinked]) {
            NSLog(@"App linked successfully!");
            // At this point you can start making API calls
        }
        return YES;
    }
    // Add whatever other url handling code your app requires here
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: I don't think you have a choice about where `openURL` is implemented. I believe it has to be a member of your `UIApplication` class (typically in a file called `AppDelegate.m`).

Answer (score 0):

[image]In info plist url type --> in url schemes just add db-YourAppKey this method will get called.

> This method is getting called automatically. I hope you already created app from dropbox developer site and get the appKey and appSecret. Use this code in app delegate NSString* appKey = @"";

```
NSString* appSecret = @"";
        NSString *root = kDBRootDropbox;
        NSString* errorMsg = nil;
        if ([appKey rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] invertedSet]].location != NSNotFound) {
            errorMsg = @"Make sure you set the app key correctly in DBRouletteAppDelegate.m";
        } else if ([appSecret rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] invertedSet]].location != NSNotFound) {
            errorMsg = @"Make sure you set the app secret correctly in DBRouletteAppDelegate.m";
        } else if ([root length] == 0) {
            errorMsg = @"Set your root to use either App Folder of full Dropbox";
        } else {
            NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Info" ofType:@"plist"];
            NSData *plistData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
            NSDictionary *loadedPlist =
            [NSPropertyListSerialization
             propertyListFromData:plistData mutabilityOption:0 format:NULL errorDescription:NULL];
            NSString *scheme = [[[[loadedPlist objectForKey:@"CFBundleURLTypes"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"CFBundleURLSchemes"] objectAtIndex:0];
            if ([scheme isEqual:@"db-APP_KEY"]) {
                errorMsg = @"Set your URL scheme correctly in DBRoulette-Info.plist";
            }
        }

        DBSession* session =
        [[DBSession alloc] initWithAppKey:appKey appSecret:appSecret root:root];
        session.delegate = self; // DBSessionDelegate methods allow you to handle re-authenticating
        [DBSession setSharedSession:session];
        [DBRequest setNetworkRequestDelegate:self];
       // [[DBSession sharedSession]unlinkAll];

        if ([[DBSession sharedSession] isLinked]) 
        {
            isAccountForDropBox = YES;
        }
        else{
           isAccountForDropBox = NO;
        }
```

//After using this that open url will get call automatically.

Comment: Yeah. Hopefully i created app in Dropbox, and i got App-key,Secret key, i used in My Appdelegate.m, but How can i implement your code on my Custom Class. Can you help me. ?

Comment: i already followed their document its working fine.But my Requirement is i need to use these into my custom class. thats it.

Comment: In info plist url type --> in url schemes just add db-YourAppKey this method will get call no need for app delegate code also. I have updated document just check it.

Comment: Hello. friend. Everything is working fine. But i don't want to use these statements in APPDELEGATE.m. You got my requirements. pls?

Answer (score 0):

These method only respond in AppDelegate.m,you can't use outside it.
 To use in your ViewController or any class, you should use post notification

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url
    sourceApplication:(NSString *)source annotation:(id)annotation {
    if ([[DBSession sharedSession] handleOpenURL:url]) {
        if ([[DBSession sharedSession] isLinked]) {
            NSLog(@"App linked successfully!");
            // Post Notify here
             [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"applicationDidLinkWithDropbox"   object:self];

        }
        return YES;
    }
    // Add whatever other url handling code your app requires here
    return NO;
}
```

Then receive this notification in your class, in a ViewController for example:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(dropBoxDidLink:)
                                                     name:@"applicationDidLinkWithDropbox"
                                                   object:nil];
}
- (void) dropBoxDidLink:(NSNotification *)notification {
    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"applicationDidLinkWithDropbox"]) {
    //Handle your task here

    }
}
```